# cannot get sc.exe to work for my program

Tags: windows, service

I am trying to follow [this website](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) and install a program we have as a service.

This is what I have:

```
SC CREATE SqlPort binPath= “D:\RPG\VbLib\SqlPort\SqlPort\srvstart.exe SqlPort -c D:\RPG\VbLib\SqlPort\SqlPort\sqlport.ini” DisplayName= SqlPort start= auto
```

When I hit enter, it gives me the help:

```
DESCRIPTION:
        Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
USAGE:
        sc <server> create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
       (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

I've compared the help to what I have and I don't see any problems with it. This is on a Windows 7 x64 system.

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You've got `“` and `”` in the pasted text. Might want to try replacing them with plain `"` quotes instead.

Comment: dangit that was it... post this as an answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got `“` and `”` in the pasted text. Might want to try replacing them with plain `"` quotes instead.

Answer (score 15):

I've had this exact problem and my quotation marks were fine...  Finally figured it out -- there *must be* a space after the '=' !

I.e. this was not working/causing the 'help' dump:

```
C:\>sc create "My Service" binPath="C:\MyService\MyService.exe"
```

But this worked:

```
C:\>sc create "My Service" binPath= "C:\MyService\MyService.exe"
```

The behavior depicted in the original question is more "generic" than improper quotation marks.  It is how the OS reacts to commands that were *improperly formatted in any way*.  It could be *any* non-ANSI character, or some other problem with the command format (e.g. misspelling "binPath", etc.)

Comment: Weird, I'm sure that I've had instances where it's worked fine without the space (e.g. https://serverfault.com/a/647201/236916), but today yours turned out to be the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Three things are very important.

1. `binPath= "` should be written instead of `binPath="` or
   `binPath = "`

> Pay attention for space

2. `"` must be written correctly

> Incorrect `“`, Correct `"`

3. cmd.exe run as administrator

**Sample**

```
sc create "Service Name" binPath= "E:\ServiceFolder\ServiceName.exe"
```

Also note that you'll need a space for every optional attributes as well.

For instance `start=auto` should be `start= auto`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had not escaped one of the internal double quotes.

Had:

```
sc config postgresql-x64-13 start= auto displayname= "PostgreSQL Server 13" binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-x64-13\" -D \"D:\PostgreSQL\13\data" -w"
```

Needed to escape the end double quote after D:\PostgreSQL\data:

```
sc config postgresql-x64-13 start= auto displayname= "PostgreSQL Server 13" binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\pg_ctl.exe\" runservice -N \"postgresql-x64-13\" -D \"D:\PostgreSQL\13\data\" -w"
```

The error message was the same:

> "A space is required between the equal sign and the value."

And, it was not helpful at all.